# Auto-number pictures

Tags: image, autonumber

I have an entertainment blog with a lot of pictures. Can someone please help me with a code that auto-numbers the pictures inside a post? (eg: www.chive.com, www.acidcow.com)

This is my CSS for pictures if it helps for anything...

```
 .post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img,

 .BlogList .item-thumbnail img {
 padding: $(image.border.small.size);

 background: $(image.background.color);
 border: 0px solid $(image.border.color);

-webkit-border-radius: 18px;
-moz-border-radius: 18px;
border-radius: 18px; 

-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);}
```